Can't create or edit a Campaign Influence Model
I created a custom Campaign Influence Model in my sandbox. Worked great.  Normally I would have deployed that model via our DevOps vendor (Gearset) but as of this writing, they don't yet support deployment of CampaignInfluenceModel
So, I thought I would go into PROD and just create it manually. How hard could that be?
No dice -- after Setup > Campaign Influence > New Attribution Model, I get a screen that looks like this:

There are no fields ?!?

Campaign Influence is definitely turned on
My user has Permission Set License CRM User (enables Campaign Influence app permission)
My user has a permission set that includes Campaign Influence

Why was I able to create the model in the sandbox but not PROD?

The first clue is the page layout as presented to me.

The absence of any fields suggests a page layout assignment issue
But there is no Campaign Influence Model in Setup > Object Manager to locate the page layout
Sheepishly, I contacted SFDC Support and they pointed out a Knowledge Article with the solution

You have to use URL hacking to get to the Campaign Influence Model page layout assignment
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/_ui/common/config/layout2/LayoutMappingUI/e?type=CampaignInfluenceModel


Assign the layout to your Profile and any other profiles that would need to edit (view) a Campaign Influence Model

Now why did I have the Campaign Influence Model layout assigned in sandbox but not PROD?

No idea; hypothesis is that PROD org is very old (ca. 2005) but full copy sandbox (where influence model was done initially) is newer (ca. 2018) and SFDC evolution of orgs over myriad release updates drifted.

